# Test the data is the same in Amazon S3 (Athena) after migration from Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Data is migrated from legacy Oracle DB into Amazon S3 buckets. Schemas are exactly the same in both. I can write individual queries on both systems, like row count and Date diff to make sure data is the same, but is there an approach to test at a larger scale on both platforms, across all columns at once in a specific table?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve done data reconciliation in the past via SQL alone; in simple cases (e.g. 2 datasets) it’s very easy with SQL set based operations (using a combination of union, minus) as per simple 2-way reconciliation pattern* (below):

```
/* Pattern query for data reconciliation test:
Data differences between the two sets would be the output if there are differences; …
these rows would be the ones to deep dive on to understand/explain the differences.  
No rows selected means there are no differences
N.B. the data source connection credentials would be embedded in the database link
*/
(
/* all rows in app1.tableX@link1 that are not found in app2.tableX@link2 */
select col1, col2, col3 /* … */ from app1.tableX@link1
minus
select col1, col2, col3 /* … */ from app2.tableX@link2
(
union 
(
/* all rows in app2.tableX@link2 that are not found in app1.tableX@link1 */
select col1, col2, col3 /* … */ from app2.tableX@link2
minus
select col1, col2, col3 /* … */ from app1.tableX@link1
)
;
```

The results of these kinds of queries can easily be saved off via 
“create table as select …” 
or 
“insert into as select …”